# Error when I try to deserialize a list form jyson

Tags: java, json, jersey

In my application client ( Rest service), I try to unmarshal a jyson list of " Region" to List but I got this Error :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.List out of START_OBJECT token  
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@d324076; line: 1, column: 1]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:160)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:198)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:103)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:93)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2131)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1395)
at ma.specificationWeb.client.RegionClient.getAllRegions(RegionClient.java:109)
at ma.specificationWeb.web.RegionAction.index(RegionAction.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There is my client side :

```
public List<Region> getAllRegions() {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,
            Boolean.TRUE);

    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(REST_URI_REGIONS);

    ClientResponse response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }
    String resultat = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(resultat);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Region> regions=null;
    try {
        regions = objectMapper.readValue(resultat,List.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return regions;
}
```

And there is my bean Region :

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="T_REGION")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"idRegion", "nomRegion"})
public class Region implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idRegion;
@Column(name = "NOM_REGION", nullable = false, length = 30, unique = true)
private String nomRegion;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "region", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Province> provinces = new ArrayList<Province>();
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "region")
private List<ActualiteRegion> actualites = new ArrayList<ActualiteRegion>();

public Long getIdRegion() {
    return idRegion;
}

public void setIdRegion(Long idRegion) {
    this.idRegion = idRegion;
}

public String getNomRegion() {
    return nomRegion;
}

public void setNomRegion(String nomRegion) {
    this.nomRegion = nomRegion;
}

public Region(String nomRegion) {

    this.nomRegion = nomRegion;
}

public Region() {
}
@XmlTransient
public List<Province> getProvinces() {
    return provinces;
}

public void setProvinces(List<Province> provinces) {
    this.provinces = provinces;
}
@XmlTransient
public List<ActualiteRegion> getActualites() {
    return actualites;
}

public void setActualites(List<ActualiteRegion> actualites) {
    this.actualites = actualites;
}

}
```

There is the method wich generate the list of "Region".

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Region> getAllRegions() {
return dao.getAllRegions();
}
```

When I receive the json list in the client side, I try to print it as a String in the console, and there is wath I have :

```
{
"region":   [
    {"idRegion":"4","nomRegion":"Oriental"},
    {"idRegion":"5","nomRegion":"Hoceima Taza Taounat"},
    {"idRegion":"6","nomRegion":"Rif"},
    {"idRegion":"7","nomRegion":"Rabat"}
    ]
}
```

There is the configuration that allow the automatic marshal and unmarshal with of json object :

```
    <display-name>hbo-go-services</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml           
    </param-value>

</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet-jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ma.noyauSolution.metier</param-value>
    </init-param>
<!--        intègre jersey avec jackson : -->
<!-- allow to marshal  a java object to a json file and to unmarshal a json file to java object   -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet-jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I hope that somenone can help me.

Comment: Can you post your application context configuration and your full rest service class containing `getAllRegions`? I followed [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) but could not reproduce the wrapping when I added an additional service that returns a list.

Comment: There must be some additional configuration that tells jackson or JAXB to use a root element as shown in [this documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html#d4e949)

Comment: I have posted the method wich produce the list of "regions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assure the json sent to your client starts with "{" which is the START_OBJECT token mentioned in the exception's stack trace...
But deserializing a List or an Array (that is not container inside an object) will require a "[" as the start token.
So please check the code that generates the json if it produces something like:

```
[
    { /*attributes of region1*/ },
    { /* ... */ },
    ...
]
```

**Edit:**

The json-String produced is representing an Object with 1 single property named "region" that contains the desired region list (`List<Region>`). When trying to deserialize this outer Object to a List it will fail, since the json parse will expect an start_array token ("[") but will receive a start_object token ("{") instead. There are now two options on how to correcty produce/parse the string:

1. change the json output to the format I mentioned above (the part of your result without the { "region": stuff in the beginning). Unfortunately I haven't worked with `@Produces` yet and I don't know the exact location that finally produces the json from the given list - there must be some wrapping object that creates the surrounding `{ ... }`. But there is still option 2.
2. create a wrapper object for deserialization:
   Since json expects an Object (an no array) you may deserialize the given list by telling the jackson parser to use a wrapper object instead, e.g.

   ```
   public class RegionWrapper
   {
       public List<Region> region;
       /* 
        name and type are important here!
        your json string names the list "region", not "regions"
       */
   }
   ```

   Then instead of reading the result to `List.class` you can write

   ```
   RegionWrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(resultat,RegionWrapper.class);
   List<Region> regions = wrapper.region;
   ```

Comment: You think I should edit the annotations of my bean "Region" ?

Comment: The Region class looks fine for me. I think its a bug in the client code. Can you post the code that generates the json and the plain message before deserialization

Comment: In the server side, there is the method wich generate the json list, it's a simple @Produces("application/json") I will post it in  a new Answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @ultimate it's working for me. I used the second option. So in this way, I have to create a wrapper object for all my package entities ( I have 14 beans ). There is another solution to factor the code ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to avoid writing those 14 wrappers when using option 2... But if you can give me some more details on where the serialization takes place on the server I'm sure we can find the spot that wraps the list into the object as the "region" propery. Any file that is related to the configuration may help here...

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post. I added my cnfiguration of jerseyin the server side, where I allow the operation of marshaling and unmarshaling automatically.